# File name for .stix files

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add this particular file extension (.STIX) in my Jquery upload method to accept files of this extension. I am already having quite a few other extensions which are getting uploaded and basically I am passing the file name along with the extension.

Working Examples:**Name:** Outlook data files **Extensions:** pst 
                 **Name:** Excel documents **Extensions:** xls,xlsx,xlsm,xltx,xltm,xlsb,xlam,csv
                 **Name:** Word documents **Extensions:** doc,docx,docm,dotx,dotm

I adding files with the extension .stix, but I am not sure what these kinds of files are called. I already tried Stuffit X, Stuffit Expander, StuffIt files etc but nothing seemed to be working.

Here is the JQuery upload method:

```
bindUploader = function () {
        $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
            // General settings
            runtimes: config.runtimes,
            url: '/safesend/upload.ashx' + '?id=' + config.id, /**/
            max_file_size: config.maxFileSize,
            chunk_size: config.chunkSize,
            unique_names: false,
            headers: { '__AntiForgeryToken': config.requestToken },

            // Browse filters
            filters: [
                { title: "All files", extensions: "*.*" },
                { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png,tiff" },
                { title: "XML files", extensions: "xml" },
                { title: "PDF documents", extensions: "pdf" },
                { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" },
                { title: "Text files", extensions: "txt,log" },
                { title: "Powerpoint documents", extensions: "ppt,pptx,pptm,potx,potm,ppam,ppsx,ppsm,sldx,sldm,thmx" },
                { title: "Excel documents", extensions: "xls,xlsx,xlsm,xltx,xltm,xlsb,xlam,csv" },
                { title: "Word documents", extensions: "doc,docx,docm,dotx,dotm" },
                { title: "Outlook data files", extensions: "pst" },
                { title: "StuffIt files", extensions: "stix" },
            ],
            preinit: {
                Init: function (up, info) {
                    $('.plupload_header, .plupload_start').remove();
                }
            },
            init: {
                UploadProgress: function (up, file) {
                    bumpProgress(up, file);
                },
                StateChanged: function (up) {
                    if (up.total && up.files && up.total.uploaded === up.files.length) {
                        var parent = $('#upload-status').parent();
                        $('#upload-status').fadeOut('slow').remove();
                        $('#send-status').appendTo(parent).fadeIn('slow');

                        __doPostBack('ctl00$Content$btnSendMessage', '');
                    }
                },
                FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                    var i = 0;
                    while (i++ < up.files.length) {
                        $('#btnSendMessage').removeAttr("disabled");
                        var ii = i;
                        while (ii < up.files.length) {
                            if (up.files[i - 1].name == up.files[ii].name) {
                                up.removeFile(up.files[ii]);
                            } else {
                                ii++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                QueueChanged: function (up) {
                    if (up.total.size > config.maxQueueSize) {
                        $('#upload-warning-modal').modal('show');

                        if (up.total.queued - 1 >= 0) {
                            up.removeFile(up.files[up.total.queued - 1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: 'assets/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',

            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url: 'assets/js/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'
        });
    },
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: Please can you show us some code? I have no idea why you would need to know the "correct" name for a type of file, how (and why) you would restrict the extensions a user could name files before uploading them, or what any of this has to do with jQuery.

Comment: StuffIt files have the suffix `sitx` not `stix`.

Comment: Yes, even I think its sitx and not stix. I have asked about the same to the concerned person and waiting for the reply. Anyways thank you for your reply t.niese!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it was sitx and not stix. And "StuffIt files" worked fine for sitx files. –